# White box when exporting

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export

When exporting a tiff in Photoshop to PNG (any format get's same issue) I get a white box around some of the shadows. If I export just the shadow layer, this doesn't show up, only when the foreground is present. I have tried changing every option I can see, but no luck. If I scale it down to 50% the artefact goes away, but I want to be able to export at 100%.

100% Scale
[image: At 100% scale, this white box shows up]

50% Scale
[image: 50% scale, there is no box]

Comment: My *guess* would be the shadow has  bending mode such as Multiply applied. PNGs **can't** contain bending modes. Possibly related: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/125762/how-to-get-images-as-if-they-are-in-the-multiply-blend-mode

Comment: Flatten the image before you attempt to export it. PNGs don't have layers anyway.

Comment: I tried both of the above and it didn't help unfortunately. Flattening the layers places the box there permanently.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a background yellow below on the second layer. If it doesn't change the problem is your second layer which you need to paint through a brush or shape then color it yellow.